# 12.04 Boot hangs after "Checking battery state", video card Intel Gma 4500Mhd

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

on my thinkpad T400, Ubuntu 12.04 hangs after "Checking battery state" and I have to boot the unity shell using startx in tty1 . My video card is an Intel Gma 4500Mhd. I cannot reinstall Ubuntu (because I have big software installs).
It came after an upgrade. Maybe it is a shell problem.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

When using the recovery mode root console, Xorg -configure leads to an error:

```
could not create lock file /tmp/tx0-lock
```

Can you help please?

Comment: In recovery mode the file system is read only. If you type `mount -o remount,rw /` it will remount the filesystem as normal, so do that and try the X command again - might give you a better error.

Comment: Thanks Tim, with `mount -o remount,rw /` I was able to run X -configure, it gives the error message : `Number of created screens does not match number of detrected devices. Configuration failed. ....error(2)` with or without my external VGA screen plugged in.

Comment: If X crashes on login it will bounce you straight back to the login screen. Is that what you are getting or is it actually hanging? Also check for the file .xsession-errors on your user's home directory - that should give you some more sensible errors.

Comment: thanks. But I have login disabled. So it does not bounce back to login, it displays the log lines in tty7, ending by "checking battery state". .xsession-errors is confusing, I don't what to do with that.

Comment: up up up up up up